# Authenticate to sharepoint online from non .net platfom

Tags: authentication, token, office365, sharepoint-online, office-app

I want to authenticate to my sharepoint online portal from any office app. So as first step i'm trying to get token from https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf but i can't do it. My code as below. I searched internet but all codes are same and like below. I can't find any solution.

```
    $.ajax({
    'url': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf',
    dataType: 'text',
    type:'POST',
    'data': '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><s:Header><a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue</a:Action><a:MessageID>urn:uuid:40c1407d-b2a4-4e05-8248-8a92b71102b6</a:MessageID><a:ReplyTo><a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address></a:ReplyTo><a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf</a:To><o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><u:Timestamp u:Id="_0"><u:Created>2012-07-26T16:13:00.622Z</u:Created><u:Expires>2012-07-26T16:18:00.622Z</u:Expires></u:Timestamp><o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-69882db9-2d6b-45d3-b016-c2156cb6c01d-1"><o:Username>userID</o:Username><o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</o:Password></o:UsernameToken></o:Security></s:Header><s:Body><t:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust"><wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"><a:EndpointReference><a:Address>url</a:Address></a:EndpointReference></wsp:AppliesTo><t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey</t:KeyType><t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType><t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion</t:TokenType></t:RequestSecurityToken></s:Body></s:Envelope>',
    headers: {
        Accept : "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8"
    },
    success: function(result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log('done in login ');
        console.log('result '+result);
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( result );
        console.log("xmlDoc:"+xmlDoc);
        var xml = $( xmlDoc )
        console.log("xml:"+xml);
        var binToken= xml.find( "wsse\\:BinarySecurityToken" ).text();
        console.log("Binary Token:"+binToken);
    },
    error:function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown+'error login:' + jqXHR.responseText);
    },
    complete:function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log('login completed ' + textStatus);
    }
});
```

What am i missing? Is there any way/suggestion to do this. 
Thanks for any help!

Edit: It was worked successfully but now i can't get token. binToken is null. i still can't get token.